# Google Map wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, plugins

I am having trouble with a plug-in for word press which has very little documentation about it. I am working on http://goo.gl/fgVM and where ever the marker is, it has NO ACTION on click, whats strange is that a pop up appears if I install this plug-in on another theme/install. I was wondering if anyone with Google map API knowledge can see if there is anything conflicting?

Answer (score 1):

There is a JS error: Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined

Comment: Cheers dude! Sorry but I am pretty crap with JS, do you have any idea how I can resolve this? Or a link to anything I could read up on?

Comment: The error is present on pages of the site where the map isn't used - that means there's an issue with your theme for sure. On line 28 is the error: `<body class="blog" onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">`. That `initialize()` is undefined. If you can see that same source in your header.php, try removing it and see what happens.